# multiple statements on if statement without curly braces

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am using an onclick function in my html (so not a method, but the javascript code itself in the html button onclick event).

How do I add 2 statements in the 1 line after an IF statement, that is not surrounded by curly braces.

I want to do something like this

```
onclick="javascript: if ( days.value == '' ) alert('Please select at least 1 day to schedule this report') && return false;"
```

I can't use the curly braces to enclose the two statements because I can't find any information on outputting a curly brace into a string in PHP (If i do, the output stops after the first curly brace)

My PHP looks like this:

```
$content["PREPEND"].= " onclick=\"javascript: if ( days.value == '' ) alert('Please select at least 1 day to schedule this report') && return false; \"";
```

I tried using the &&, but that doesnt work. Any advise appreciated!

Comment: is there any specific reason to not make an on click method?? because you are messing your code if you will do that with out any standard.

Comment: Is this line being generated within a quoted PHP string?

Comment: Had to leave this for a while, otherwise was on verge of saying something nasty.  From what I can tell there is no reason in PHP why you can't use { and } characters.  Could you please update your question showing the exact output (from the browser source) that you're getting?  My gut feeling is that your template is parsing the string and trying to do something with the brackets.

Comment: Yep found that it was the templating engine. In the html template, you use the {CONTENT} as place holders, so curly brackets are a no-no.

Comment: @Lock would you mind if I amended my answer to reflect the "template parsing"?

Comment: By all means. I managed to set a {SCRIPTS} variable in the head to output script references but would love to hear your input

Comment: I apologise, but its actually quite selfish... after being wrongly flamed (and downvoted) by YourCommonSense, it would be nice to have recognition that I was on the right track. I understand if you'd prefer not too. Unfortunately, as I have no knowledge of your template system (or even what it actually is) I very much doubt I have any more input

Answer (score 2):

Javascript code has nothing to do with PHP code. 
You may use whatever braces you want.

If something goes wrong with whatever curly braces - you are just putting them in wrong way. **You have to correct your braces then**, instead of looking for some ugly way to avoid them.

Correcting errors is a quite trivial task in programming, you know.

If it's indeed PHP code does interfere with your JS (I cannot be sure as you didn't post not even a single PHP operator in your questions), just close the PHP mode and write your JS as is, as though it's just a pure HTML page:

```
//some php
// then close it
?>
<a href="#" onclick='javascript: if ( days.value == "" ) { alert("Please select at least 1 day to schedule this report"); return false; }'>
<?php
// open PHP back
```

if you need some PHP values inside of JS - open PHP again:

```
//some php
$var = "test";
// then close it
?>
<a href="#" onclick='javascript: if ( days.value == "<?=$var?>" ) { alert("Please select at least 1 day to schedule this report"); return false; }'>
<?php
// open PHP back
```

Comment: Well PHP does have something to do with it because PHP outputs the the strings in which the JavaScript is part of:

Comment: Not when a curly brace is added into the variable, as PHP is seeing the curly brace as a language construct of some sort. If I could escape the curly brace, i would, but I can't see anything on the internet about escaping curly braces in PHP so that it will output the curly brace into the actual string

Comment: PHP is looking for the language constructs only inside it's tags. So, instead of writing JS inside PHP strings. just close yopur PHP tag and write your JS as is, as though it's just a pure HTML page. See the edited answer

Comment: I can't write is as pure HTML as this system uses a tempate engine, which outputs the variables onto a HTML template. Basically, ALL HTML is part of a PHP variable ($content["PREPEND")

Comment: OMG, write your JS as a part of the TEMPLATE, not PHP code then! Otherwise using such a "template engine" will make absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing, have you tried inverting the quotes (turning the doubles into singles, and singles into double)?  PHP treats strings created with double quotes differently to those with singles...

```
onclick='javascript: if ( days.value == "" ) { alert("Please select at least 1 day to schedule this report"); return false; }'
```

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with the listed statement

Comment: He's tagged the question with PHP and mentioned PHP in the question therefore I'm led to believe the HTML is being created through PHP, therefore I believe it's the quotes that are the problem.  Care to remove my down vote?.

Comment: These poor noobs just tag their questions at random :) One have to use their *experience* (if any) while reading the question, not blindly trust to tags. This statement cannot be inside of the PHP quoted string. So, inverting the quotes makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, I'll take the bait... exactly *why* cannot it be inside of a PHP quoted string?  What exactly points to the fact that this HTML hasn't been created via an PHP quotes string?  And as a "poor noob", I take exception that we all don't know how to use the system

Comment: just because he doesn't have either quotes *escaped*. You cannot mix different quotes in the PHP string without escaping delimiting quotes. It should be like this `$str="onclick='javascript: if ( days.value == \"\" )...";` if it were inside of PHP string.

Comment: This is true, but I believe he's showing the final HTML output, not the source code.  I'm hoping they will respond to my above question to clear this up, and I will update my answer should I be completely wide of the mark

Comment: @freefaller is entirely correct.  Question explicitly states that this JavaScript is output by PHP.

Comment: Poor noobs? Do you think i'm going to tag a question as PHP (and mention it in my code) if it has absolutely nothing to do with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

First of all its a bad practice.
But you could add duplicate if to return false

Answer (score 0):

Put the two statements into a javascript function and then call the function in the if-statement.

Comment: I want to try and avoid this if possible as the header of the pages are not very accessible

Answer (score 0):

"I can't use the curly braces to enclose the two statements because I can't find any information on outputting a curly brace into a string in PHP (If i do, the output stops after the first curly brace)" - Can't you just print '{...}' print a curly brace?